# Moving from parent theme to child theme without losing configurations

Tags: child-theme

I am moving from parent theme to child theme on an ecommerce website. When I move to the child theme, the parent themes configrations are removed and the site's design starts looking ugly. In order restore the parent theme configuration, the `theme_mods_theme_name` row in `wp_options` table needs to be changed to `theme_mods_child_theme_name` and before that the entry for `theme_mods_child_theme_name` which was created when moving to child theme needs to be deleted. Doing these changes on the live site directly is dangerous. How can I write a script that that does the configuration change automatically? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obvious solution: **don't switch on the live site**. You could use a staging environment instead, but this can become tricky with ecommerce sites if orders have been placed in the meantime. Alternatively shut down your site for a couple of minutes.

---

If this is not feasable, there may be other ways. To understand, how theme switching works, [check out the `switch_themes( $stylesheet )` function](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/theme.php#L679) in wp-includes/theme.php. This is the function that manages transition from one theme to another.

I see many ways that you could inject your custom code in there somewhere, you'll have to test which way fits your needs best.

1. Listen to `update_option( 'theme_switch_menu_locations', ...` change. This is probably one of the first ways you could inject custom code in. However, here you do not really know the the new template
2. Listen to `update_option( 'stylesheet', $stylesheet )`, here you know the new theme (`$stylesheet`) and can get the currently active one via [`wp_get_theme()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_theme/). The theme hasn't switched completely yet, so you can still create the new options as you see fit
3. Either listen to `update_option( 'theme_switched', $old_theme->get_stylesheet() )` or to `do_action( 'switch_theme', $new_name, $new_theme, $old_theme )`. The theme switch for most parts has already happened, default values will have been set and visitors in the meantime will see your "ugly" site.

I would probably go for solution 2. (ok, false, I wouldn't do these changes on a live site). The new options have not been checked/set yet, so you can copy what you need from the old template and prepare these values. So when WordPress checks for the settings, you'll already have them pre-filled.